# Cannot create stream pipeline using transform streams

Tags: node.js

This is my code:

```
stream = require 'stream'
stringer = new stream.Transform objectMode: true
stringer2 = new stream.Transform objectMode: true

stringer.push 'hello'
stringer.push 'world'
stringer.push null


stringer2._transform = (chunk, enc, done) -> 
    console.log chunk.toString()
    done()
    return @

stringer.pipe(stringer2).pipe process.stdout
```

I am able to log each individual chunk in `stringer2` but im unable to pipe the result to `stdout`. How do I do this?

Comment: could you replicate this on plunker/fiddle?

Comment: AFAIK codepen/fiddle/plunkr cant run nodejs snips...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `this.push(chunk)` to pass the transformed chunk on to the next pipe. You can omit `return this` as well, although it won't hurt anything.

In coffeescript, it will look like this:

```
stringer2._transform = (chunk, enc, done) ->
    console.log chunk.toString()
    @push chunk
    done()
```

Or, as a shortcut, you can pass the chunk to `done()` as the second argument (the first is an error, or null if there is no error):

```
stringer2._transform = (chunk, enc, done) ->
    console.log chunk.toString()
    done null, chunk
```